# How to write a negative cyper query pattern

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Cypher and Neo4J and I am doing the online getting started course for Neo4J and came to a page where it asks to find actors that worked with Gene Hackman in movies that Robin Williams wasn't in.  The example query was this:

```
MATCH (gene:Person {name:"Gene Hackman"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie),
(other)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie), 
(robin:Person {name:"Robin Williams"})
WHERE NOT (robin)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie)
RETURN DISTINCT other;
```

Is it possible to formulate a negative pattern in the match that does not rely upon the WHERE clause to exclude results?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the `WHERE`?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, `MATCH` is only for things that exist in the graph. Finding something that must not exists, aka negative pattern, is solely possible with a `WHERE NOT` filter.